# MariaDB cant save utf8mb4_unicode_ci value

Tags: linux, database, mariadb

so i have a MariaDB database version: `10.6.12` on Ubuntu version: `22.04.1`. Now i have created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_saver` (
  `user_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(254) NOT NULL
) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Now i want to insert `ღ`. It keeps giving me "Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9D\x95\x9A\xF0\x9D...' for column `alldaybot`.`user_saver`.`user_name` at row 1" error. It does work on another machine. How can i troubleshoot this?

- Reinstall MariaDB, creating a new table
- I did this insert: `INSERT INTO user_saver (1, 'ღ');`

Answer (score 0):

Ah I've had this same issue before:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_database';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation_database';
```

Make sure that the character_set_database and collation_database match the settings in your table definition. If the settings are not consistent try changing the character set and collation of the user_name column to match those of the other machine where it works.

run `my_print_defaults --help``

to find where your conf file is and you might want to set:

```
[mysqld]
character_set_database = utf8mb4
collation_server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```